# Объекты обертки. Вызов методов напрямую на числах

Tags: javascript

В `JS` есть 6 примитивных типов: `number`, `string`, `boolean`, `null`, `undefined`, `Symbol` и 7 тип `object`.

**Примитивные типы не имеют своих свойств и методов** однако у типов `number`, `string` и `boolean`есть объекты-обертки которые имеют ряд предопределенных свойств и методов упрощающих работу с этими типами данных. При обращении к методам на вещественных значениях последние могут быть временно преобразованы в соответствующие объекты-обертки, подобно конструкторам `new String()` , `new Number()` или `new Boolen()` и действовать в роли объектов, обладая свойствами и методами.

Мне не понятно почему у типов `string` и `boolean` обертки создаются как при вызове методов напрямую на значении так и на переменной которая хранит примитивное значение а с `number` только если вызвать метод на переменной но не на значении.

**Примеры:**

```
const str = 'hello world'
str.toString() // => "hello world"
'hello world'.toString() // => "hello world"

const bool = true
bool.toString() // => "true"
true.toString() // => "true"

const num = 5
num.toString() // => "5"
5.toString() // => Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

Comment: а если число обернуть в скобки — `(5).toString()` — то работает

Comment: потому что точка это разделитель дробной части для чисел, не?

Comment: @teran та да, спасибо, видимо в этом проблема. UPD  `5.11.toString()` работает. первая точка это разделитель. Нужно этот вопрос удалить?

Comment: @torokhkun можно написать ответ и выделить, как верный. Думаю, что вопрос вполне нормальный

Comment: Кстати, есть еще тип `Symbol` :)

Comment: У меня стойкое ощущение, что такой вопрос был уже, но что-то найти не могу

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все дело в том что **все числа в `JS` это числа с плавающей точкой**. То есть - могут иметь дробную часть. Поэтому в выражении `5.toString()` интерпретатор воспринимал точку не как оператор вызова метода, а как разделитель целой и дробной части. Ожидая после разделителя числа и не получив их интерпретатор и выбросил исключение.

**Для того чтобы на числах вызывать методы объектов-оберток нужно**

взять число в скобки

```
(5).toString() // => "5"
```

перед оператором вызова метода поствить еще одну точку - разделитель дробной части

```
5..toString() // => "5"
```